# linode vs amazon ec2 vs heroku for project with amazon s3

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, cloud, vps, linode

**I have a project in ruby on rails 3.1 like flickr, tumblr, pinterest...etc with a lot of pictures for maintenance.**

My project have database Mongodb.

I'm using amazon s3 for host pictures.

**I want to know what is the best hosting combination to get the most quality/price, linode + s3, or amazon ec2 + s3 or heroku + amazon s3.**

I need enough scale because the project is growing fast.

**Any other suggest is welcome :D.**

After much reading I am not clear.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want to save the most money then I'd go with [linode](http://www.linode.com/) (Amazon ec2 might cost about the same though). With linode for $19.95/month you  get 20gb of space where you can host your website and database. If you're using s3 then you can use most of the 20gb for your database. Not only that but on linode the addons that would cost you money on Heroku will be free (solr/sphinx, background jobs, email, etc). Compare this to Heroku where a 20gb shared database alone costs $15/month. Then you need to pay monthly if you want solr, background jobs, etc.

On linode it's free because you run and maintain your own virtual private server (VPS). Which brings me to one of the most important things to consider here, **linode will save you *money* but it will cost you more *time*** since you have to manage everything yourself.

For what it's worth, I am currently in the process of moving much of my hosting over from Heroku to Linode because of the costs involved and because as a rails developer I feel it's important to understand how to manage my own webserver.

There are a lot of other advantages to having your own VPS though. For example, hosting multiple website, creating multiple databases used by other web apps, your own email server, etc.

---

Update: April 2014

An even cheaper alternative to linode is [digitalocean](http://digitalocean.com/). Their cheapest plan is currently $5/month.

Comment: Thank you I'm using linode and its very very good. I'm having a lot of problems configuring the server, database, nginx, unicorn ... etc, but because I am beginner running a vps with ruby on rails .. But I have much more flexibility. In the end I chose linode. Thank you very much!

Comment: @hyperrjas one last thing than I want to mention is that I usually start a project on Heroku because that's the quickest way to get up and running. Then later on, if I need something that would cost me money on Heroku I switch over to Linode. (eg. larger database than 5 megs, background jobs, etc)

Answer (score -1):

Just for a performance point of view, you'll get better performance if you use EC2 or Heroku since both are parts of the Amazon infrastructure (Heroku runs on EC2).

But it will only benefits if your pictures are processed by your Python server. If your pictures are served directly to the client, it will not have any impact to use Linode :)

Comment: "you'll get better performance" - Care to be a bit more specific? Linode's always performed better for me (perhaps I got lucky with node allocation on Linode or unlucky on EC2 or something). I've also had no downtime on Linode in over a year, whereas my EC2 instance has had to be restarted no less than 3 times over the same period due to hardware failures (and after each restart the IP address changed, causing DNS issues).

Comment: It was just regarding the question which was "I have S3, and which is the better EC2 or Linode ?". I was talking about networking performances, since S3 is a part of the Amazon infrastructure, so S3 and EC2 are on the same "virtually" network.

Comment: He's probably serving the images directly from S3 to the client, which means the internal network is no benefit.